# How to extend date in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I have the following dataframe. How can add next n=6 months to the end of date and appoint new value=0. I run the following code, but I will get an error.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar


date=['2000-01-01','2000-02-01','2000-03-01','2000-04-01','2000-05-01','2000-06-01','2000-07-01' ]
value=[5,6,2,7,5,6,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date,value)),columns =['date','value'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')


n=6
end_point = len(df)
x =df.at[end_point - 1, 'date']
days_in_month=calendar.monthrange(x.year, x.month)[1]

for i in range(n):
    df.at[df.index[end_point + i], 'date'] = x + timedelta(days=days_in_month + days_in_month * i)
    df.at[df.index[end_point + i], 'value'] = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
dti = pd.date_range(df['date'].max() + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), periods=6, freq='MS')
out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'date': dti, 'value': 0})], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
         date  value
0  2000-01-01      5
1  2000-02-01      6
2  2000-03-01      2
3  2000-04-01      7
4  2000-05-01      5
5  2000-06-01      6
6  2000-07-01      2
7  2000-08-01      0
8  2000-09-01      0
9  2000-10-01      0
10 2000-11-01      0
11 2000-12-01      0
12 2001-01-01      0
```

Answer (score 0):

First I imported the whole of pandas for convenience and aliased it (not sure how you were accessing it as pd before).

Then changed the 'end_point' to subtract 1 when it is declared, not when it was used (doesn't fix functionality, just makes it easier to understand).

Then rewrote the last function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar


date = ['2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2000-03-01',
        '2000-04-01', '2000-05-01', '2000-06-01', '2000-07-01']
value = [5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 6, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, value)), columns=['date', 'value'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

n = 6
end_point = len(df) - 1
x = df.at[end_point, 'date']
days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(x.year, x.month)[1]

# loop to add 'n' amount of new rows
for i in range(n):
    df.loc[end_point + i + 1] = [x + timedelta(days=days_in_month + days_in_month * i), 0]

print(df)
```

Let me know if this works - or gets you where you want to be :)